# Using the tables in SQLExpress database for authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

ASP.NET MVC 5 authentication has user tables in the localDB by default. However, I have created my database in SQLEXPRESS with IIS, and I want the authentication module to use these tables in SQLEXPRESS database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Change your connection string to point at the SQLEXPRESS instance.

Comment: If I change the connection string for Identity to point to the SQLEXPRESS DB, I get this error; "Directory lookup for the file "F:\Academic\ASPproject\MY\Mysolution\MYsolution\MYsolution\App_Data\aspnet-EMRs‌​olution-20150615092849.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.). CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors."

Answer (score 0):

You can reconfigure the context used by Identity to point to your other database.  I'm assuming you've been using one connection for Identity and another for the other SQLExpress database.

```
public class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUsers>
{
     public IdentityDbContext() : base("MySqlExpressConnection") {}

     static AppIdentityDbContext()
     {
          Database.SetInitializer<IdentityDbContext>(new IdentityDbInit());
     }         
}

public class IdentityDbInit : NullDatabaseInitializer<IdentityDbContext> {}
```

If you've been using the one connection for Identity and simply wish to add the Identity tables to a different, existing database, just change the connection string to point to your SQLExpress database.

Comment: When reconfigure the context as you have explained, I get this error: "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context." If I change the connection string for Identity to point to the SQLEXPRESS DB, I get this error; "Directory lookup for the file "F:\Academic\ASPproject\MY\Mysolution\MYsolution\MYsolution\App_Data\aspnet-EMRsolution-20150615092849.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors."

Comment: I have a feeling we could get into the weeds pretty fast, so I'm going to link to a great resource that helped me include Identity in a recent project.  It's several chapter of an Apress book that were made available for free.  The author believes a paywall should not stand between you and a secure application, which is pretty awesome.

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 Platform - Free Chapters](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290)

Just scroll down to the downloads section.